# The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle spring boot problem

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm encountering a circular dependency problem in my Spring Boot application when attempting to customize the expiration time for JSON Web Tokens (JWTs) based on user preferences. After making changes to my code, I encountered the following error message:

```
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

   jwtAuthFilter defined in file [C:\Users\hp\Desktop\supfit\backend\supplement\target\classes\com\project\supplement\security\config\JwtAuthFilter.class]
┌─────┐
|  jwtService defined in file [C:\Users\hp\Desktop\supfit\backend\supplement\target\classes\com\project\supplement\security\config\JwtService.class]
↑     ↓
|  userServiceImpl defined in file [C:\Users\hp\Desktop\supfit\backend\supplement\target\classes\com\project\supplement\service\impl\UserServiceImpl.class]
└─────┘


Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.
```

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtService {

    @Value("${jwt.key}")
    private String SECRET;

    @Value("${jwt.expiration-time}")
    private long defaultExpirationTime;

    private final UserService userService;

    public String generateToken(Map<String, Object> extraClaims,
                                UserDetails userDetails){

        User user = userService.findUserByEmail(userDetails.getUsername());

        long expirationTime;

        if(user == null){
            expirationTime = defaultExpirationTime;
        }else{
            expirationTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + (user.getTokenValidation() * 60 * 1000);
        }

        return Jwts
                .builder()
                .setClaims(extraClaims)
                .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(expirationTime))
                .signWith(getSignInKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();
    }

     ...
```

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final JwtService jwtService;

@Override
    public AuthResponse updateTokenValidation(Long userId, Long tokenValidation) {

        User user = userRepository.findById(userId)
                .orElseThrow(UserNotExistsException::new);
        user.setTokenValidation(tokenValidation);
        userRepository.save(user);

        var jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user);
        return AuthResponse.builder()
                .token(jwtToken)
                .build();
    }

    ...
```

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class JwtAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String token;
        final String userEmail;
        if(authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")){
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        token = authHeader.substring(7);
        userEmail = jwtService.extractUsername(token);
        if(userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
            if(jwtService.isTokenValid(token, userDetails)){
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authToken.setDetails(
                        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                );
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Could someone please help me understand why this circular dependency issue is occurring and suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two of your beans, `jwtService` and `userServiceImpl` requires each other in order to create them. That means, Spring cannot create `jwtService` because it needs `userServiceImpl` which needs `jwtService`...

If you can't really avoid circular dependency you can use a `@Lazy` annotation to solve it.

Here is a quick example

```
@Component
public static class BeanA {
    private final BeanB b;

    public BeanA(@Lazy BeanB b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
@Component
public static class BeanB {
    private final BeanA a;

    public BeanB(BeanA a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Also, as your error message says, you can try to set up an application property
`spring.main.allow-circular-references` to true

Comment: I added the @Lazy annotation with Constructor Injection to JwtService and UserServiceImpl, and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue here is that JwtService bean references  the UserService bean; while the UserService also references JwtService bean. Specific usage wise: JwtService invokes `userService.findUserByEmail()`, while UserServiceImpl invokes `jwtService.generateToken()`.

This creates the circular dependency, which Spring no longer allows by default.  The error comes from the circular dependency injection, and not tied to the usage details, but I included those for added clarity as to why the circular dependency is functionally needed.

This circular dependency validation can technically be disabled via `spring.main.allow-circular-references`, but generally this is not considered a good practice.  In this case, it can easily be resolved otherwise…

The most straightforward way to address this circular dependency would be to refactor out the UserServiceImpl.updateTokenValidation() method needed by the JwtService, out into a new separate strategy.

Some possible naming for this new strategy may include: `UserTokenService` or `UserTokenUpdateSevice` or `UserAuthService`.

So then the JwtService can invoke this new UserTokenService.updateTokenValidation() strategy method, and remove its injected dependency on UserService.  UserServiceImpl is then free to retain its dependency on JwtService to enable the invocation of `jwtService.generateToken()`.